# Как Заблокировать исходящий трафик определенной программе в linux ubuntu?

Tags: linux, трафик

Необходимо программе langq запретить исходящий трафик с машины ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Наверное тебе надо копать в сторону `ufw app info`. И\или https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch